# Check Update permissions on object instance/record

Tags: permissions, standard-objects

Is it possible to check if I (current SF user) can update a given object instance?

We can use `Schema.sObjectType.Contact.isUpdatable()` to check if the current user has permissions to update Contact objects in general (Please correct me if I'm wrong).

However, it's possible that we might come across another `Contact` instance (EDIT: i.e a record) which we can not update because it's owned by someone else.

My question is, can I check if a particular standard object instance (EDIT: i.e a record) is updatable instead of checking on the class in general?

Comment: Do you want to check if a particular record is updateable by a user?? Then you should check the share table table for that object.. The line Schema.sObjectType.Contact.isUpdatable() will result true if the current user's profile has EDIT permission on the contact object

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want! Would it be possible for you to give a quick example, or a link to such as I'm pretty new with SF, ideally as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query the `UserRecordAccess` table (documentation is [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm)) to find out what permissions a particular user has on a particular record of an object. This table allows you to construct the following query:

```
SELECT RecordId, HasEditAccess
FROM UserRecordAccess
WHERE UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
AND RecordId = <<record Id>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also build a custom sharing button for each object to help make UserRecordAccess accessible in a non-programmatic way. Check out the custom sharing button blog post on salesforcehacker - http://www.salesforcehacker.com/2013/09/build-your-own-custom-sharing-button.html.